# sync Ad custom atrbute with userprofiles

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, central-administration, ad

I have tried and failed to use the built-in UI to map some custom properties from an AD over to SharePoint.

That is when I went over to a Powershell script that can do the same.

The problem I'm facing now is "unable to process put message"

I have googled it extensively and I have done all the permission for FIM, also the permissions for the UserProfile account are in all the places that all the blogs and tech articles suggest. But I'm stil having the issue with the error message.
[image]

p.s. disregard the random numbers and letters in the picture. (debugging stuff)

Any help on how to fix the "unable to process put message" error?

Comment: If the UI won't do it I'd troubleshoot that. What error are you getting in the UI and what is showing in the ULS Logs? What version of SharePoint?

Comment: SP 2010. ULs logs are useless as they dont show anything remotely usable.

Comment: Usually that is not the case. Usually the ULS logs contain the info to track this kind of issue down. Are you in a single or multi server environment? Are you certain that your account has full control of the UPA?